# Java Script filter condition in dynamics 365

Tags: javascript, filter, conditional-statements, jscript

i want to add an extra parameter for my filter condition but i dont know how to do it.

At the moment we select all accounts with the businesstypecode "3", but i want to select the codes "4" and "5" as well.

I just need a simple "or" but i work with JScript for the first time ^^

```
    Filter.filterMaschinenringAccounts = function () {
        var maschinenringFilter = "<filter type='and'><condition attribute='businesstypecode' operator='eq' value='3'/></filter>";
        Xrm.Page.getControl("mrd_lu_zugehoeriger_mr").addCustomFilter(maschinenringFilter, "account");
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Léon